# Redirect a user after successful login, Wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, url

When a user attempts to view a restricted page they're moved to a login page which lets them login and continue onto that page. I'm wondering how to redirect users to that restricted page after they successfully login.

Here's the code for the submit button:

`<p class="submit">
<input id="wp-submit" class="button button-primary button-large"
name="wp-submit" type="submit" value="Log In" />
<input name="redirect_to" type="hidden" target="/" />`

Comment: and your question is?

Comment: numerous plugins available for this

Comment: If you're using wordpress and have no programming skill whatsoever, then go learn PHP or JavaScript first. If you're using wordpress and you have programming experience, then use either `<?php header('Location: http://www.example.com/'); ?>` or `window.location.replace(http://www.example.com/);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

once the user hits a restricted page, you can store the page/url they are trying to access in the $_SESSION variable.
see [more info here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php)

Then redirect them to the login page.

If they log in successfully, redirect them back to the url you stored in the $_SESSION variable.